# Auto Logout from Epic Games Launcher

Tags: c#, sdk, game-development, desktop-application

I've been working on a project where I need to implement an auto-logout feature for various game launchers like Steam, Battle.net, and GOG. This functionality is straightforward with most launchers, as simply closing them from the task manager triggers the logout process if the "stay signed in" option isn't checked.

However, I'm facing a challenge with the Epic Games Launcher. Unlike other launchers, simply closing it from the task manager doesn't seem to trigger an automatic logout, even when the "stay signed in" option is unchecked.

I've explored the Epic Games documentation and forums but haven't found a clear solution for this issue. Can anyone provide guidance or suggest a workaround for implementing auto-logout functionality specifically for the Epic Games Launcher?

```cs
using System; 
using Epic.OnlineServices; 
using Epic.OnlineServices.Auth; 
using Epic.OnlineServices.Platform; 
class Program 
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        try
        { 
            Initialize EOS SDK var initializeOptions = new InitializeOptions(); 
            Epic.OnlineServices.Platform.PlatformInterface.Initialize(ref initializeOptions); 
            // Create a callback object for logout 
            var logoutCallback = new Epic.OnlineServices.Auth.OnLogoutCallback((ref LogoutCallbackInfo data) =>
            { 
                // You can handle the logout callback here if needed
                if (data.ResultCode == Result.Success)
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine("Logged out successfully");
                } 
                else
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to log out"); 
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + data.ResultCode); 
                    // Optionally provide more details about the error
                }
            }); 
            // Create an instance of AuthInterface 
            var authInterface = new AuthInterface(); 
            // Replace "YOUR_EPIC_ACCOUNT_ID_HERE" with your actual EpicAccountId 
            var localUserId = EpicAccountId.FromString("71dd7e2e115641eb93e3fb9c49c40e45"); 
            // Log out of the Epic Games account 
            var logoutOptions = new LogoutOptions();
            logoutOptions.LocalUserId = localUserId; 
            authInterface.Logout(ref logoutOptions, IntPtr.Zero, logoutCallback); 
            // Shutdown EOS SDK 
            Epic.OnlineServices.Platform.PlatformInterface.Shutdown();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Here is a link to help you format your code so that it's more readable. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code